# R: What do I do about "Error: columns ``" and then a list of column names

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has ~30K rows and ~450 columns.

I'd like to filter out a particular field.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% filter(name != "")
```

I get this error

```
Error: Columns `column_one`, `column_two`, `column_three`,
```

It goes on for 44 columns. I've never seen this error before.

For what it's worth, I made the data frame by taking five CSVs and joining them together in a command like this one.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)

invoicesJoined <- invoices %>% 
                    plyr::join(table_one, by = "joinkey_one", type = "inner") %>% 
                    plyr::join(table_two, by = "joinkey_two", type = "inner") %>% 
                    plyr::join(table_three, by = "joinkey_three", type = "inner") %>% 
                    plyr::join(table_four, by = "joinkey_four", type = "inner") %>% 
                    plyr::join(table_five, by = "joinkey_five", type = "inner")
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using plyr::join() rather than inner_join() given that you've loaded tidyverse? Also, just to be clear, you're trying to filter out rows where the name column is empty or NA?

Comment: The recommendation for inner_join did the trick. Both tables had `joinkey_one` and plyr::join was adding the row after the join, meaning there were two columns with the name `joinkey_one`. I think that messed it up.

Comment: inner_join() renames them to `joinkey_one.x` and `joinkey_one.y` and then I just chose one of them to be the join for following tables.